# What am I supposed to do if a teammate starts firing at me in World of Tanks?

Tags: world-of-tanks

It sometimes happens that a teammate deliberately tries to kill you for example if you stand in his way. It often happens on Province or Malinovka that I hide behind a rock next to the spawn area and snipe from there. Sometimes someone else tries to push you out and if it does not work they start firing at you.

In these cases I ask them to stop but 80% won't do so and in this case standard procedure for me is to ensure survival: I kill them and continue the game. Today I received an 1H ban because of "Team Kill" but in fact it was self defense. What can I do in these cases? Just standing there until I die is not an option.

Comment: It's quite possible that these people are perceiving what you are doing as camping, which is generally frowned upon. If that is the case, then the way to get them to stop is not to camp in the first place. Have you actually asked them *why* they're attacking you?

Comment: No. I'm camping because I think it is fine on Malinovka and Province. No amount of convincing will make me think otherwise. Don't tell me not to camp because I like to camp on those maps and this won't change. Plus firing at an ally without warning is not acceptable in any circumstance.

Comment: Some people take the same view on camping. If people are trying to team kill you because you're camping, you have four options; accept that it will happen and continue playing, stop camping, find a group of players that don't care if you camp or don't play the game at all. Camping is **always** going to make you unpopular with people on both sides, being killed by them for it is one of the consequences.

Comment: I don't get it. Camping is usually frowned upon that's fine. It won't work in 95% of the cases but those 2 maps are an exception to the general rule. In most of those games I tend to do a lot of damage, sometimes I get High Caliber and we often win. I'm usually driving a tank destroyer or a sniper tank.

Comment: What you are trying to say is not the problem I think. Most people are firing at me because they *want to camp behind the rock I'm camping* and they can't push me out.

Comment: You're expecting people to be *reasonable* or *sensible* - which they aren't...

Comment: I think I'll have to write to Wargaming support.

Comment: No camping? That's ludicrous. Several tanks exist for sniping in mind. Practically the entire TD line, especially the less mobile ones. I find it's even encouraged, as some tanks are not good for anything else.

Comment: @Nix again, you expect people to be reasonable or logical? Remember the average age (mental or otherwise) of teamkillers is adolescent, if that. Yes, camping can be bad, it can be good. I've had games where everyone scrambled for the first bush they saw and sat there, waiting for nothing to happen. Bad. Other games, everyone rushes headlong for the enemy base without thinking about cover or anything. Bad too.

Comment: I'm not expecting everyone to be model gamers, but I think saying that "camping is frowned upon and you shouldn't do it" is incorrect and bad advice. There will be snipers in almost every battle, and that's fine, because the game caters to them. I play mostly TD and arty, and have never experienced animosity for "camping". Au contraire, it's way more likely to see people go nuts when all the TDs rush out and leave the base unprotected! Sure there are idiots in the flock, but they are thinned out as you progress to higher tiers.

Comment: @Nix I've had team mates scream they're going to report me for being an afk camper while playing arty or when hanging back in a TD to catch leakers... It indeed gets less severe at higher tiers, the worst of it seems to be at 4-6. Though now being in a clan might help, if you're in a clan many people seem to think you know what you're doing, lolz

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is integrated mechanisms to handle these sort of things, and the system knows how to tell the difference between accidental and intentional team damage.

For example, an artillery unit who hits an enemy unit, but simultanously does splash damage to nearby friendly units is not nescesarilly sanctioned, although they will pay a fine to repair the friendly tank. As a frequent arty player, I have accidentally killed friendly unites several times – it sucks, but as long as you don't make it into a pattern, you're cool.

Players who continues to shoot on friendly units, or who shoots a friendly unit immediatly after the battle starts, are marked blue in the list. This carries on over to their next games, and is a warning to the player – if they continue, they will receive sanctions.

The blue status also lets other players know, to look out for this player. If you damage or kill a player that has been marked, **you don't receive a fine or penalty to your score**:

> The system will additionally flag players who have destroyed several allied vehicles over a number of games. The name of such a player will appear blue in your team list. If a player on your team appears as blue – and only then – everyone on your team can attack and destroy that player’s vehicle without a penalty.

You will, however, receive a -1 to your counter. Don't be alarmed by this:

> Please note that while you are not penalized for destroying a blue
>   allied vehicle, you also don’t get any credit for doing so – it is
>   basically neutral – however, your counter will still be decreased by
>   one for every allied vehicle destroyed (blue or not).

The system will know which players do team damage and team kills, and will be dealt with automatically. You do not need to report people who do team damage:

> A Global Rating system which tracks Friendly Fire from the account
>   over a period of time and a Local Rating system which tracks Friendly
>   Fire within a specific game.
>
> As a result, no reports of friendly fire are required nor are they
>   considered. All tickets sent to the support team to report team
>   killers will be replied stating this information and directed to this
>   post for more information.

However, you can report the player in-game. This is done by Ctrl-clicking the player name, whereafter a context menu shows up. In this, you can choose to report the player. After the battle, you can right-click the player in the battle report to get the same menu.

[image]

Read more about the [complaint system](http://worldoftanks.eu/en/content/guide/general/complaint-system/).
Read more about [reporting a player](https://eu.wargaming.net/support/Knowledgebase/Article/View/66/18/how-do-i-report-an-in-game-rule-violation).
Read more about the [automated system for registering team damage](https://eu.wargaming.net/support/Knowledgebase/Article/View/46/0/how-does-the-in-game-automated-system-for-team-killing-work).

Comment: So there is no real solution for the problem.

Comment: That's a real solution. There is not magical button to let you kick people that bother you

Comment: last I heard you no longer get a mark for killing off a marked teamkiller since 9.2. The survival rates for blue players reflects that, they rarely make it out of the starting circle :)

Comment: One point worth noting is that the system pays increased attention to team damage near the cap points, so if somebody's shooting you, getting to the cap can help them get marked sooner so you can fire back without penalty, or even get them banned.

Answer (score 1):

Far more often it's idiots who just shoot randomly while rushing out from the start area, hitting half their own team before anyone even spots an enemy.

As said, there's automatic penalty systems in place to detect and punish them. They get fined your repairs, if they do it enough they get banned. Which you encountered ;)

First ban is an hour, second is a day, third is 3 days, fourth is permanent (or something along those lines).
Tends to give people pause to start teamkilling, and I guess it does. Haven't seen much deliberate teamkilling lately.

Answer (score 0):

Most TKers won't listen to reason, so there is no point in trying to reason with them.

Camping may be unpopular, but that doesn't mean it is an invalid/bad tactic as there can be very good reasons to do so.  In fact I'd argue that the meatgrinder mentality which many players have is worse.

When people FF me I usually say something to them in chat, and if that doesn't have any effect (usually the case) I try to bait them into TKing me so that they will cop a ban, or perhaps block them in somewhere inconvenient (this is easier when playing TOG :D) until they apologise.

I'll usually blacklist them and add a note explaining why I did so - "TKed me at start of round" etc

I'd like to think people wouldn't TK but with a free-to-play game there is less incentive for people to behave.